# Java & SQL prepareStatement error (Parameter index out of range)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert

I've been trying to fix a part of my code that throws a

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

I already searched stackoverflow and other parts of the internet but couldnt find the solution, that corrected the error.

This is the start of the class file:

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
```

And this is my constructer:

```
public DataAccessObjectImpl() throws Exception {
    this.conn = new DBConnector();
}
```

This is the method thats cause the problem:

```
@Override
public boolean addAlbum(int UID, String artist, String album) {
    String sql = "";

    try {
        stmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO music (identifier, UID, artist, album) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
        stmt.setString(1, getNewIdentifier());
        stmt.setInt(2, UID);
        stmt.setString(3, artist);
        stmt.setString(4, album);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("nugget 1 : " + ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Nugget 2 : " + e);
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

(the word "nugget" is just so its easy for myself to find in the log / console)

From what i could gather on stackoverflow its probably my question marks thats the problem, but I can't seem to figure out how. I used prepareStatement for other methods thats working just fine in the same class.

---

I have some working code I provided down below, I want to replace this code with preparestatement to patch SQL Injection:

```
try {
        stmtb = conn.getConnection().createStatement();
            sql = "INSERT INTO music VALUES ('" + getNewIdentifier() + "','" + UID + "','" + artist + "','" + album + "')";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
return false;
```

Thank you in advanced!

---

Fixed by changing this line:

```
stmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO music (identifier, UID, artist, album) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
```

and i changed it to this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (?);");
```

and deleted this line:

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
```

Thank you Kayaman for the help!

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` when displaying exceptions. You get a lot more information out of them (such as the line where the exception occurred).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're not executing the query that you think you're executing.

Comment: Thank you Kayaman for the expanded search, I found the problem to be at "stmt.setInt(2, UID);" Even though I still hasnt found the solution to fix the problem.

Comment: Then double check, and triple check your query. It's correct in your question, but is it correct in your code?

Comment: 'Sadly' its the same in my Query, I came to the same conclusion from what I seemed to be able to find from other post. http://i.imgur.com/xoENsD0.png or atleast I can't find the difference between these 2.

Comment: Try putting `PreparedStatement stmt = conn.getConn.. etc.` in there. It doesn't make sense to share the `stmt` reference anyway, and that might be fudging up the actual query you're trying to execute.

Comment: THANK YOU! That fixed it! Is there someone way to choose a comment as answer? Otherwise just post that as a answer and I will mark it right! Its really wierd since we learned to do it that other way (share the stmt) in my computer science study.

Comment: If that hadn't worked, the only remaining explanation would've been a cursed JVM ;)

Comment: Would make sense also, again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query is correct, but the exception occurs, the only possible explanation is that the `stmt` gets corrupted somehow. The only realistic situation would be in a multi-threaded environment with multiple threads using the same `stmt` to perform queries.

Since you're using `prepareStatement()` to create a new `PreparedStatement` object, there's no reason to share a "global" reference. In most cases the best practice is to define and use variables in the smallest scope possible.

Therefore remove the `stmt` variable from the outer scope, and instead just write

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
```

where ever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, which works, UID is passed like a `VARCHAR`, because it is surrounded with `''`

```
sql = "INSERT INTO music VALUES ('" + getNewIdentifier() + "','" + UID + "','" + artist + "','" + album + "')";
```

Please, re-check database schema and ensure that UID is `INTEGER`. Also you may try to replace

```
stmt.setInt(2, UID);
```

with

```
stmt.setString(2, Integer.toString(UID));
```

to replicate simple `Statement` behaviour.

Comment: UID is   "`UID` int(255) NOT NULL,", I've tried to change that to "`UID` integer(255) NOT NULL," sadly it still won't work. I also checked my code trough again to make sure its a int.